# Surprising result with lambdas

Tags: python, lambda

I am obviously misunderstanding how lambda works here:

```
def get_res_lambda():
    res = []
    for v in ['one', 'two', 'three']:
        res.append(lambda: v)
    return res


def get_res():
    res = []
    for v in ['one', 'two', 'three']:
        res.append(v)
    return res

print ">>> With list"
res = get_res()
print(res[0])
print(res[1])
print(res[2])

print ">>> With lambda"
res = get_res_lambda()
print(res[0]())
print(res[1]())
print(res[2]())
```

I get:

```
>>> With list
one
two
three
>>> With lambda
three
three
three
```

I was expecting:

```
>>> With list
one
two
three
>>> With lambda
one
two
three
```

Why is the lambda version returning always the last value? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: By using a `lambda`, you implement *lazy* evaluation: the result is only evaluated when you call the function, and at that stage, `v` has value `three`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem A generator implements lazy evaluation, lambda implements an anonymous function. Nothing lazy about it.

Comment: This question is asked approximately every day.

Comment: @delavnog: Of course this is lazy. Say you would have written `lambda: very_expensive_operation()` and `very_expensive_operation` either does a lot of calculations or sleeps for 300 seconds, do you think it will be executed before you call it with `res[0]()`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Calling the lambda function happens when you call the lambda function, of course, like every function. Your hint about lazy seems to imply that the value returned by the function (v) is computed when the function is called. This is not true: the value is already set when the function is defined. It is the way in which the value is set in the closure where the lambda function is defined that affects the result. You'll get the exact same problem by using a def instead of lambda, and you will agree with me that def is not lazy.

Comment: @delavnog: indeed the function *construction* is not lazy, but the function *execution* is lazy, and meanwhile the value of `v` has changed.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Then we agree. Your original comment was "by using a lambda", which seems to imply that lambda has implicit lazyness. It is just the fact that it is a function, which is evaluated on call. The strange result is coming from how closures and loops are managed in python, not directly due to a strange lambda side-effect, which was my first thought.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your lambda function returns the value of `v` at the point the lambda function is executed. The lambda function is executed when you reach `print(res[0]())` etc.

By that time `for v in ['one', 'two', 'three']` has already completely finished its loop, and `v` has its final value, `'three'`.

Comment: Replying to your first version: I do not think lambdas are deferred evaluation. I think this has to do with how closures are handled in python

Comment: I edited the formatting of my answer, but not the content. I don't know what in my "first version" you think you're arguing with.

Comment: I was arguing against supposed lambda lazyness.

Comment: No previous version of my answer mentioned laziness any more or less than it does now.

Comment: I can not see the previous version, so can't comment exactly.